# How to get timezone RAW Offset? Node.JS

Tags: node.js, timezone, offset

When you go to https://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/Europe/Berlin it says raw_offset=3600 , i'm trying to get this value in Node.JS. Need help please, i'm giving my code below but it's giving me wrong output

```
const moment = require("moment-timezone");
let timezone = "Europe/Warsaw";
let haha = moment().tz(timezone);
let timezone_raw = haha.utcOffset()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doesn't look wrong they just use a different format.
Worldtime-API seems to use seconds where moment.js seems to use minutes.
According to my test moment.js also returns 60 from `utcOffset()`.

You can either take the `raw_offset` and divide it by 60 (seconds per minute) to get 60 (minutes).
Or you can take the return from `utcOffset()` and multiply it by 60 to get 3600.